# Trimming AI file white space

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, crop, white-space

I am using an old, old CS2 version of illustrator and have designed my art (about 2" x 3" in size) on an 8.5" x 11" page in AI. How do I reduce all the white space around my design so that when I place it in InDesign, I do not have the full 8.5 x 11 page. Do I simply change the document size if I want less white space?

(I know, as soon as my CS2 fails me, I will buy the subscription.)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone wants to perform the action in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017.

**Menu:**

```
Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork Bounds
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've used CS2, but you should be able to change the setting from within InDesign. When you place the file, check the box at the bottom of the dialog box that says, "Show Import Options." Then under Options > Crop to: > ART.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the size of your page in Illustrator. Since a few versions back they are called artboards but in version CS2 they are called a *Crop Area* (or was it crop mark?).

1. You can **release** the current crop area. I think the menu is `Object > Crop Area... > Release`
2. You will get a rectangle that has no fill and stroke color. In your case it'll be 8.5" x 11" in size.
3. Resize this object or delete and draw a new one with the position and size you'd like.
4. Make sure this new rectangle is selected and **make** a new crop area. This time: `Object > Crop Area... > Make`

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first suggestion and it worked, except the language was "Crop to: Bounding Box". I really appreciate the help!